# Android O : Notification channel for Incoming call

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo, incoming-call, notification-channel

Introduction of notification channel allow many apps to remove their notification settings in app and redirect to device settings. Which is quite easy for developers as the framework itself will handle notification sounds.

Incoming call ringtones can be played via Ringtone manager or Media player. We cant play incoming call ringtone using notification because notification sound stops when the notification tray is opened.

Initially i created notification channel with IMPORTANCE_LOW so that there is no sound for incoming call notifications. There may be situation where user can assign sounds to incoming call notification where both sounds are played (sound set by notification channel and Incoming call ringtone which is handled by app).

This is a big problem for all calling apps. Can any one have solution for it ?

Comment: If a tiger is coming with roaring loud towards you.., do you need any notification from him to hide yourself or for running away...?? ( As he don't know how to speak your language to notify you ) ... But Yes ... If you hide yourself and becomes safe when tiger is went away... Then ... Now you can become tiger and even make a loud roaring sound like being a tiger..!!

Comment: What are you trying to say ? sandhya